# Why was my suggested edit — to Mitsu Haideshi's answer with many separated links — rejected?

Tags: discussion

[Here's my suggested edit.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/28707) 1. Mitsu Haideshi wrote

> I would posit two things -- the subject - object - verb word order plus the use of particles, adding in the very unusual use of wa/ga in Japanese or eun-neun/ga-i in Korean, is an extremely rare grammar in the world.

This appears ungrammatical, and I rectified it to

> What is extremely rare are 1. the subject - object - verb word order plus 2. the use of particles, adding in the very unusual use of wa/ga in Japanese or eun-neun/ga-i in Korean.

2. Doesn't embedding links make a post easier to read?

Answer (score 2):

The edit was rejected as "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

I was one of those who voted to reject, so placing my answer here.

First, I'd like to tell that the Reject reasons are not very accurate, and you can't write a long response like I'm doing now. Sorry I was too lazy to formulate my point.

1. See the partial screenshot below how your edit looks like in Side-by-Side Markdown mode. I recall I was dazzled by the difference, too. Hence the "deviates from the original intent". I admit it could be a software bug because your edit is not *that* drastic. Switching to Side-by-Side mode makes it look fine;
2. There's a consensus that edits must be as complete as possible. In other words, embedding hyperlinks or fixing grammar like double dash to m-width dash **is certainly good**, but it may not be sufficient. Here's how they put it on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/):

   > Suggested edits are intended to be substantive and improve the post overall, rather than just focusing on one issue. Keep in mind that all edits, no matter how major or minor, require the same amount of reviewer effort and award the same amount of reputation; allowing extremely minor edits wouldn't be fair to other users who take the time to suggest more substantive improvements.

   > In some cases, you may believe that there is only one thing that needs to be changed. But in 99.9% of cases, there is something else that could use some revision as well.
3. The post contains long paragraphs with no or vague references. While not a "crime" by itself, it usually suggests that the post may need being "wikified" or shortened. Which, in turn, may require a discussion with the OP in a chain of comments;
4. On the other hand, you've missed some double-dashes thus making the edit inconsistent;
5. You seem to have removed some paragraphs marks, I'm not sure why. To my subjective view, the post already looks like a large wall of text.

P.S. You do a great job with your other edits; I have just approved your two other edits. One minor suggestion: not everything needs a link to Wikipedia. :)

P.P.S. The OP may override the outcome of the Review and approve your edit even though it has been originally rejected.

[image: Screenshot]